# Django Admin - How to prefill add inline forms values sent through the querystring?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, inline-formset

I am able to prefill a form using query-string parameters in Django Admin.

Let's say I have the following models:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.Autofield(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)


class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.Autofield(primary_key=True)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
```

If I go to `/admin/library/author/add/?name=J.+K.+Rowling` the author's name will be properly prefilled.

However if I add InlineForms like that:

```py
class BookInline(StackedInline):
    model = Book
    extra = 0

class AuthorAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInline]

admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

I don't seem to be able to prefill books.

I tried: `/admin/library/author/add/?name=J.+K.+Rowling&books-TOTAL_FORMS=1&books-0-name=Harry+Potter+and+the+Philosopher's+Stone`

The author form is prefilled, but the first book form is not prefilled. Do you know how one manages that?

Comment: A first thought would be to override `get_inline_instances` in order to add initial data from `request.GET`

Comment: Alternatively, overridding `get_formset_kwargs` might work.

Answer (score 1):

If you override `get_formset_kwargs`, you can prefill forms with some initial values:

```py
class AuthorAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BookInline]

    def get_formset_kwargs(self, request, obj, inline, prefix):
        formset_params = super().get_formset_kwargs(request, obj, inline, prefix)
        if request.method == "GET":
            # Mind you, this will prefill all form of the formset with the same values.
            # But for our usecase it is sufficient.
            prefix_length = len(prefix) + 3
            initial_values = [{key[prefix_length:]: value for key, value in request.GET.items() if key.startswith(prefix)}]
            formset_params.update(initial=initial_values)
        return formset_params
```

However, all extra form will contain the same values.

If you know how we can manage to use the index there, it would improve this answer.